# Does the sentence "You ate so many!" make any sense?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Normally, you often hear "**You ate so much!**". It seems that "**much**" here is food and food is uncountable noun so we use "**much**".

But let see this sentence "**There were 50 candies on the plate, but now they re all gone. You ate so many!**". We use "**many**" because candy is countable noun.

**Does above sentence make any sense?**

Comment: Yes, because we use "many" for countable things, and "much" for uncountable things.  So *many* apples, but so *much* pudding.

Comment: @stangdon, why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"You ate so many" is absolutely right in that context. The words "many" and "much" can function as pronouns. "Much" replaces a non-count noun and many a count noun. Since "candy" is being used as a count noun above you use "many"

- You ate so many (candies)
- You ate so much (candy)
- You ate so much (food)

all correct

- You ate so much candies.

Incorrect